# using method 'build_standard_field(self, field_name, model_field)' to overcame the error [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I'm writing a Django Rest Framework, and I want to use a **generics.CreateAPIView** to create an operation in my database.
my **models.py**:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField("Email Address", unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField("Last Name", max_length=150)
    mobile = models.CharField("Mobile Number", max_length=150, blank=True)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0.0, verbose_name=("Balance"))
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("Created at", auto_now_add=True, editable=False)


class Operation(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name=("Sender"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name=("Receiver"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0.0, verbose_name=("Amount"))
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("Created at", auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
```

I want to send uuid values when creation the operation and handle the users filter in the backend using the view.
So I added extra fields to the serializers as this:

```py
class OperationCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sender_uuid = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex_verbose')
    receiver_uuid = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex_verbose')
    amount = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, coerce_to_string=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Operation
        fields = ["sender_uuid", "receiver_uuid", "amount"]
        write_only_fields = ["sender_uuid", "receiver_uuid"]


class OperationListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Operation
        fields = ["sender", "receiver", "amount"]
```

The **Problem** is when I try to create the transfert operation I get error `[<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]` for the field `'amount'` in the view.
The logic I'm using in my view is:

```py
class TransferView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = OperationCreateSerializer
    queryset = Operation.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = OperationCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            print(serializer.validated_data.get('amount'))
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            with transaction.atomic():
                sender = User.objects.filter(uuid=serializer.validated_data.get('sender_uuid'))
                if sender and sender[0].balance >= serializer.validated_data.get('amount'):
                    User.objects.filter(uuid=serializer.validated_data.get('sender_uuid')).update(balance=F('balance') - serializer.validated_data.get('amount', 0))
                    User.objects.filter(uuid=serializer.validated_data.get('receiver_uuid')).update(balance=F('balance') + serializer.validated_data.get('amount', None))
                    serializer.save(sender=User.objects.get(uuid=serializer.validated_data.get('sender_uuid')), receiver=User.objects.get(uuid=serializer.validated_data.get('receiver_uuid')))
                    return Response({'message': 'transfer done successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_201_OK)
                else:
                    return Response({'message': 'insufficient balance'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class TransactionViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = OperationListSerializer
    queryset = Operation.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Restricting the returned purchased Operations to a given a date range query 
        parameter in the URL.
        """
        start = self.request.query_params.get('start_date')
        end = self.request.query_params.get('end_date')
        try:
            queryset = self.queryset.filter(Q(created_at__range=[start, end]))
            return queryset
        except Operation.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
```

I don't know what is the probleme with the `Decimale` value of the field, I found that there is way to map extra-fields `fields = ["sender_uuid", "receiver_uuid"]` that I'm using to send uuid value to the backend with the apropriate field in the models `fields = ["sender", "receiver"]` using the methode

[> build_standard_field(self, field_name, model_field)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#the-field_class-and-field_kwargs-api)
I don' know how to use this method and why I get the error when trying to create my instance.

**Edit**:
this is the error I get:

```
Internal Server Error: /v1/api/transfert/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 190, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/payment_api/account/views.py", line 30, in create
    serializer.save(sender=User.objects.get(uuid=serializer.validated_data.get('sender_uuid')), receiver=User.objects.get(uuid=serializer.validated_data.get('receiver_uuid')), amount=decimal.Decimal(serializer.validated_data.get('amount')))
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 431, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 68, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1122, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "/home/mohammed/Projects/PaymentSystem/paymentsys/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py", line 313, in converter
    return create_decimal(value).quantize(quantize_value, context=expression.output_field.context)
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
[03/Jan/2022 15:58:16] "POST /v1/api/transfert/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145513
```

Comment: Could you share your error logs?

Comment: @P.Ezzati I added the error logs.

Answer (score 1):

The first reason, which can cause an error, is `default=0.0` inside your configuration of your `DecimalField`s. It has to be `default=Decimal(0)`; in some versions of Django, it could cause trouble.

Also, this error commonly happens when your data can't be converted to `Decimal`, especially when `max_digits` digits are not enough for your value.

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/):

> **DecimalField.max_digits**
> The maximum number of digits allowed in the number. Note that this number must be greater than or equal to **decimal_places**.
>
> **DecimalField.decimal_places**
> The number of decimal places to store with the number.

So if you need to store `1_000_000_000.00` in `DecimalField`, you have to configure it `max_digits=11, decimal_places=2`, not `max_digits=9, decimal_places=2`.

Comment: even with a decimal converter in the model field for the default value ad also in the view to convert the `amount` before saving it to the instance I get the same error. I added the whole error msg to my question

Comment: and I'm using only a small number of digits  5 digits

Comment: Hm, strange. Could you specify what a value do you have in `serializer.validated_data.get('amount')`? You can debug output it at `payment_api/account/views.py`.